# $\lim_{x \to n\pi} \frac{M^{2}\cos(2Mx)}{\cos(2x)} = M^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, trigonometry, proof-explanation

I was just informed that

$$\lim_{x \to n\pi} \dfrac{M^{2}\cos(2Mx)}{\cos(2x)} = M^2,$$

where $n$ is an integer.

What are the steps for calculating this?

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please clarify this.

Comment: For $x$ is closed to $0$?

Comment: True for any $n$ is $M$ is an integer.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Given the context, it would indeed make sense that $M$ is an integer. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any integers $n$ and $M$ we have: 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow n\pi}\frac{M^2\cos2Mx}{\cos2x}=\frac{M^2\cdot1}{1}=M^2.$$
It's not true if M is not an integer number.

Comment: Ok, I just found that they meant $\lim_{x \to n\pi} \dfrac{M^{2}\cos(2Mx)}{\cos(2x)} = M^2$, where $n$ is an integer. My apologies for any confusion!

Comment: @The Pointer It's not  true if $M$ is not integer.

Comment: Ahh, I see! Given the context, it would indeed make sense that $M$ is an integer. Thank you very much for the clarification!

Comment: @The Pointer You are welcome!